# WPF - Transparency - Stream Desktop Content

Tags: c#, wpf, streaming, transparency

Greetings

I'm in the process of making a Scoreboard for a game (Starcraft II). This scoreboard is being made as a WPF Application with a C# code-behind. I already have a version which works for 90% in WinForms but I lacked the support to easily make it look a lot nicer which are available in WPF.

The point of this application will be to form a kind of overlay on top of a running game. This game is in Fulscreen(Windowed Mode) so when in WinForms I coded it so that it should always be on top. It would do so and that was no problem.

Since the main look of the app in WPF is based on an image with a transparent background I have set most Background values to Transparent. However when I do this the entire application does not get registered by streaming software. For example it just shows my Desktop or the game I'm playing but not my application even though it IS there. I can see it with my own eyes but the audience on the stream cannot.

Does anyone have any experience with this matter because it's really doing my head in. My entire application will be useless if it is not visible on streams. If I have to put the background on a color rather than transparent the UI will be completely demolished as well in terms of looks.

I'm basically trying to make a game-overlay in C# & WPF. I have read you can do this on different ways as well but I have little to no knowledge of C++ nor do I know anything about DirectX

Thank you for your time reading and your possible insights.

Edit: The best solution would be an overlay similar to that one of Steam/Xfire/Dolby Axon.

Edit 2: I've had no luck with all the suggestions so I basically made the transparent bits of my image non transparent and let the user decide which one to use depending on what streaming software they would be using.

Comment: You might have better luck posting on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What capture software are you using to create the "stream"?  FRAPS, Camtasia, etc?

Comment: Well it's XSplit Broadcaster which is currently in Béta but it allows u to stream really good quality (HD).

Comment: Though not an "answer", but on a note of extra research into successes in this approach and industry... I'd highly recommend looking into the way Steam adds it's Shift+Tab content onto games. It shows the current time, has a web browser, friends list and interactions, and is quite useful and unobtrusive when not in use.

Comment: Steam uses hooks to get their DirectX stuff in the program or so.. I don't know much about DirectX nor C++ so I haven't got the slightest of clue where to start, but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Set explicitly Background="Transparent" to MainWindow with using AllowsTransparency="True". I read that you'd set the backgrounds, but don't know where.

Comment: @Eugene I've done that but then it doesn't show on the streaming software hehe. I've made two versions now, one transparent & one non transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with Transparency in WPF. When you set transparency to zero, it doesn't have anything to pick up. Set it to the minimum value, then streaming software will be able to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but what if you make it only almost transparent (i.e. alpha = 0.01 or so)? Then it shoud have enough "substance" to be picked up by the streaming, but still be invisible enough to not disturb the view.

Comment: The problem is the moment i set  AllowsTransparency="True", it doesnt show on the streaming software. If I set it to false there is an ugly border around the image from the Window which is not the idea =[. If i change the opacity of the window the problem is that everything in that window will become hardly visible.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm out of ideas too.

Comment: I think you have the answer there... keep the opacity of window to a low value, allow transparency to false.. but you say everything on the panel is hardly visible.. that is a graphical problem, you should choose a dark panel bgcolor like have bright text over it - or have some more panels with different colors as child controls with lower opacity again.. so the child controls will have their own opacity and the parent panel's opacity going together to give a nice feel to the area while text or score content on the child panels look just clear. What do you think ? that helps ?

Comment: The opacity doesn't seem to work when AllowsTransparency is set to false :s.

Comment: Transparency is handled by dedicated hardware on the graphics card, so is video/gaming overlay. They overlay was achieved before Windows Vista (not sure about Vista&7) was that the application presented a certain color that the graphics card would replace with the image. You can test this by screenshotting the game and holding the image over it. If you can see through then thats how the game renders. :)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the alpha-blending is being done totally on the GPU, preventing the streaming software from finding it.  So you might try forcing software rendering in your WPF app.  You can do that by setting:

`RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly`

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work either :(. As soon as my windows changes to the basic theme (streaming software does this automatically) it disappears, otherwise it does show on the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't received any response yet I thought I'd suggest a slightly different approach.

Make a WinForm which you set to MDIParent. Then you send a Win32API-command to bring the game into your application as a child window, remove the borders, maximize it.

```
IntPtr Parent = hWnd of your main form.
IntPtr hWnd = Win32.User.FindWindow(null, "TheGame");
Win32.User.SetParent(hWnd, Parent);
// Get current window style of child form
int style = Win32.User.GetWindowLong(hWnd, Win32.User.GWL_STYLE);
// Take current window style and remove WS_CAPTION and WS_BORDER from it
Win32.User.SetWindowLong(hWnd, Win32.User.GWL_STYLE, (style & ~Win32.User.WS_CAPTION & ~Win32.User.WS_BORDER));
// Maximize within parent
Win32.User.ShowWindow(hWnd, Win32.User.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Note: The Win32.User class is just a vanilla wrapper for the corresponding Win32 interop commands.

You should now be able to draw on top of this Window either by GDI+'ing directly to the hWnd or putting something on top of it. The problem you are having with transparency may require you to do some manual copying, that is you render your interface somewhere, then copy it pixel by pixel to the destination window skipping any transparent pixels.

I hope this is useful or at least can spark some ideas.

**EDIT:**
Also you may find this interesting: 
 http://blog.tedd.no/index.php/2010/08/16/c-image-analysis-auto-gaming-with-source/

The sample app allows you to modify the image before it is displayed. You just add simple modules to it that gets input and sets output. Way too slow to use for real gaming though. :)

**EDIT2:** Just came across [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Not sure if it works, but you can use this call (see my code above on finding window) to set transparency color.